# How can I push a html page from vue router rather than route to another vue component in multi-page-mode Vue app?

Tags: javascript, html, web, vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to build a multi-page app in Vue.

I want to route to another html page (from index.html to dashboard.html) on an action.

In my Vue routes.js

```
path : '/dashboard',
        name:'dashboard',
        component : Dashboard  //here Dashboard means I want to go to dashboard.html page not a vue like Dashboard.vue
    },
```

and in my template :

```
<router-link to="/dashboard">
   <a href="#" class="nav-link">Go to dashboard</a>
</router-link>
```

How can I achieve this, or is there other way to switch html page in Vue?

Comment: I dont know if this is exactly what you are looking for , but it sounds like it: https://itnext.io/anyway-heres-how-to-create-a-multiple-layout-system-with-vue-and-vue-router-b379baa91a05

Comment: I think here its [link](https://itnext.io/anyway-heres-how-to-create-a-multiple-layout-system-with-vue-and-vue-router-b379baa91a05)  routing the pages to different vue for corresponding paths, what I actually want is to change the whole html page , for instance : Now component is rendered in index.html , now app will route to dashboard or any other html

Comment: I am running this code now.
`document.open();
 document.write(response.data);
 document.close();
`
But not sure its the proper way to do this